# Find if a function is periodic

Tags: functions, problem-solving, periodic-functions

I'm looking for a way to prove that a function is periodic (or not periodic) by definition.

For example, I tried to prove that $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is not periodic by comparing it to $\frac{1}{1+(x+p)^2}$ ($p\in R$) and see if I can get a constant, and as expected I didn't.

Yet, with actual periodic function it didn't work.

How can I do it the right way?

Comment: Can you show which periodic function didn't work.

Comment: You won't get a constant unless you already know that $p$ *is* the period.  Example:  $\sin (x+p) - \sin x = \sin x\cos p + \sin p\cos x -\sin x = \sin x(\cos p - 1) + \sin p \cos x$ is not a constant unless $\sin p = \cos p - 1 =0$.

Comment: One question, isn't p a positive real number, greater than zero, and not just any real number?

Comment: $\frac 1 {1+x^{2}}=\frac 1 {1+(x+nT)^{2}}\to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)$$
$$f(x+T)=\left(\frac{1}{1+(x+T)^2}\right)$$
$$f(x)=f(x+T)$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{1+(x+T)^2}\right)$$
$$x^2=(x+T)^2$$
$$x^2=x^2+T^2+2xT$$
$$T(T+2x)=0$$
Therefore,
$$T=0;T=-2x$$

So, the values of $T$ that we've obtained aren't independent of $x$, neither are they positive real(s) greater than zero. Hence, the given function isn't periodic.

This is the method to determine if a function is periodic or not, "by definition".

If you weren't able to obtain a suitable value for T for a function you know is periodic, then you've simply made some sort of calci error.

Thus, please revert with the periodic function whose periodicity you weren't able to prove.